# Parallax effect image resized a bit on iPad and iPhone (when scrolling)

Tags: html, css, iphone, ipad

I have a parallax effect on my website. Visible here: http://www.prezzio.net at the end of the page. Everything works well but I noticed one thing on iPad and iPhone. When using Safari browser on iPad and iPhone when you scroll down on the page, the height of the header is somewhat smaller and when you scroll up the height of the header is bigger. This is the normal behaviour. This produce an effect on my parallax background (fix) image. I mean the image is resized a bit because of my image is `100% height`. I don't know if I'm clear...

I don't know how to avoid this by keeping my background parallax image fix whenever the user scroll up or down.

Comment: I don't see no header. What header? Also could you provide screenshots?

Comment: When I talked about `header` I mean the browser bar with address bar, buttons, menu, ... On iPhone and iPad this part of the browser is automatically resized when scrolling up/down.